# Baseline alignment for legacy flexboxes

Tags: css, flexbox

I am building flexboxes for a site, and the newer variety are fantastic -- working exactly as expected. Because we render to PDF using wkhtmltopdf, however, it looks like we'll need to support legacy (webkit-*) flexboxes for a while yet.

I've put together the following code to demonstrate the issue:

```
<style>
    .item {
      -webkit-box-align:baseline;
      margin:5px;
    }
    
    .wrapper {
      display:-webkit-box;
/*    display:flex;
      align-items:baseline; */
    }
</style>

<div class='wrapper'>
  <div class='item' style="width:50px;">LOOK:</div>
  <div class='item' style="width:200px;">Here's a box <div style="display:inline-block; vertical-align:-15px; height:50px; width:50px; border:1px solid black;"></div> and a bunch of text.</div>
</div>
```

When I run it using the commented (newer-style) CSS instead of the webkit-* version, I get what I expect for baseline alignment:

[image]

However, running the code as above, on either Chrome or (because it uses an old webkit engine) QtWeb, I get this:

[image]

I know that the old standards are a bit of a wild west, so it's entirely possible that this is as expected, but I find it odd that "baseline" and "start" give the same alignment in all of the cases I've tested, so before I give up on this I thought I'd check -- am I using the old standard incorrectly for baseline alignment?

Comment: Since it is a flex container property, have you tried `-webkit-box-align:baseline;` on `wrapper` rule?

Comment: Son of a... Yep, that appears to be it. I swear I saw a half-dozen examples where the webkit-box-align was on the enclosed items. Thank you.

Comment: You might not be the only one :) ... so I posted it as an answer too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `-webkit-box-align` is a flex container property, add it to your `wrapper` rule

```
.wrapper {
  display:-webkit-box;
  -webkit-box-align:baseline;
}
```